# NestJS and TypeORM issue with or without tsconfig target es5

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, nestjs, typeorm

As per NestJS authentication tutorial I copy pasted the `JwtStrategy` class but that class throws an error at build time

Class code is

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly userRepo: UserRepository) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: 'secretKey'
    });
  }
}
```

And with target=es5 in tsconfig.json file the error I get

[image]

Now if I change the target to es6 error goes away but then typeorm many to many relationship start throwing an error

TypeORM class User got tokens and Token class got user and it throws the error below

[image]

I have created the repository to reproduce the error at [this](https://gitlab.com/atul221282/special-repo) link

run following command to see the error

```
ng s --project=api
```

Comment: Could you share with us your model? From error I would say that you have circular dependency in your model.

Comment: Yes it is circular dependency error but that is how entities are designed in typeorm. If I use es5 target I don't get that error but if I use es6 target then I start getting it.

Comment: I have got the repo link in my question it can be easily downloaded and executed. It also got classes that you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing nest v5 and nest v6 although different major versions are not guaranteed to interoperate properly, e.g.:

```
"@nestjs/core": "5.5.0",
"@nestjs/jwt": "^6.0.0",
```

Please update *all* your `@nestjs` dependencies to version 6 following the [migration guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide).

Comment: Not working, I created the new project using nrwl then replaced my old package json but it didn't work